# How to check after update on maximum constraints?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table for my clients, in which I have their personal informations and a score. This score should be a number between 0 and 1000. I use MySql as DBMS, and I will update client scores by something like this query:

```
UPDATE client SET score=score+'[insertedScore]' where id='[id]';
```

in which [id] is that client's id and [insertedScore] is the points I should insert to her score. 
How can I tell mysql to check if after this update the score where more than 1000, change it to 1000?

**Note:** Performance is an important issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [`LEAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) function:

```
UPDATE Client SET Score = LEAST(Score + ?, 1000) WHERE id = ?
```

One could even implement it within a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/triggers.html), in which case your *existing* `UPDATE` command will be limited to the specified maximum value:

```
CREATE TRIGGER xyz BEFORE UPDATE ON Client FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.Score = LEAST(NEW.Score, 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something but how about the following:

```
Update Client set Score = 1000 where Score > 1000;
```

Just run it once after you've completed all the updates.

Of course the simple way is just to validate the inserted value prior to running the update and make sure it can't be over 1000. Then no update required!

**Edit**: Maybe try something like this (This is SQL Server, I know you need mySQL but hopefully the syntax is roughly the same) -

```
Update Client Set Score = 
( Case 
   WHEN score=score+'[insertedScore]' > 1000 THEN 1000
   ELSE score=score+'[insertedScore]'
  END
)
WHERE ID = '[ID]';
```

Comment: I need to update on each request and I need consistency after each update, so I can't do a batch updates then do what you told.

Comment: And I need to put it in mysql, not in my code, to save 1 query per each request (the query to ask the score)

Comment: I've updated my answer, hopefully you can translate that into mySQL? I can't check the syntax is 100% though also, so may require some tweaking!